# Hibernate Multiple @OneToMany bound to same entity type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have yet another `@OneToMany` question. In this case, I'm trying to model a person having a list of excluded people they shouldn't be able to send items to. This is a Spring Boot app using JPA.

In the code below, the `exclusions` list populates properly but the `excludedBy` List does not. Because of this, I believe that is causing the deletion of a Person that is excluded by another person to fail because the `Exclusion` in `excludedBy` is not mapped on the object properly.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
    Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    List<Exclusion> exclusions = new ArrayList<>();

    //This is not getting populated
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    List<Exclusion> excludedBy = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "exclusions")
public class Exclusion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    Person sender;

    @ManyToOne
    Person receiver;

    ...
}
```

I would expect that this would have mapped the bidirectional relationship properly and as such the `excludedBy` List would be populated as well.

Any wisdom on this matter would be great!

Answer (score 0):

1 - An `@Id` is by default not `nullable`, not required:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
```

2 - There is no need for an `@Id` in this class. Both sides of the exclusion are together unique. Not needed:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Long id;
```

3 - An "Exclusion" requires both an excludedBy and an excluded, give them names that match and they are your `@Id`. It is a 2 way ManyToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exclusions")
public class Exclusion {
    @Id
    @ManyToMany // An ID so not optional, so no need for (optional = false)
    Person excludedBy;

    @Id
    @ManyToMany // An ID so not optional, so no need for (optional = false)
    Person excluded;
}
```

Entity `Exclusion` always knows both sides of the story.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "excludedBy", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
List<Exclusion> excluded = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "excluded", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
List<Exclusion> excludedBy = new ArrayList<>();
```

Tip: JSON DTOs shouldn't be defined in your JPA DTOs, otherwise you can't change your **internal** data model independently of your **external** API model.

Comment: Hi @Bill! Thanks for the response, however even with this approach it's the same result as before. A `Person` never gets an excludedBy list populated, just exclusions. Definitely will be refactoring into API models once this is working!

Comment: What was I thinking :-) It is a ManyToMany releationship. The `exclusions` table is a 2 way join table. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the past. Your key problem ist that your ORM Mapper hibernate does not know which of your database entries need to be assinged to `exclusions` and which are assiged to `excludedBy`. You need a **discriminator** and add the constraint in your select. I would propose a solution that looks something like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRIMARY_KEX_IN_EXCLUSION_TABLE", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Where(clause = "is_excluded_by = 0")
private Set<Exclusion> exclusions; 

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRIMARY_KEX_IN_EXCLUSION_TABLE", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Where(clause = "is_excluded_by = 1")
private Set<Exclusion> excludedBy;
```

the value `isExcludedBy` needs to be a database column, part of your Entity and set in your code manually.

I think you also need to use `Set` instead of `List` when having multiple collections in one Entity. https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-multiplebagfetchexception/